# How to run Spring server app in production mode?

Tags: java, spring, server

I have followed the quickstart guide on the Spring website and successfully run the Spring app hello world server via `./mvnw spring-boot:run`.

And it works.

I did som benchmarking (on my local machine) but its on the RoR7 requests-per-second response level and I was hoping to get something at least Express like numbers - so at least something that is 15 - 20x or more times faster than RoR.

Is there a command line flag parameter like `production` or `--release` to get a release-finetuned-app` that is faster?

UPDATE:
even if I do mvn build and run java -jar and the jar target name it is still the same ruby on rails level. Fr example, an express app of that same complexity is 40x faster and in Rust(Actix) 400x faster, while it should be something like the same or faster than Express and perhaps 3 - 5x slower than Rust. I need to turn off debugging and other stuff and produce a release build of a spring app somehow. Any idea how to realize that?

Comment: Is it a web application?

Comment: What do you mean? It's on localhost, not in public. It's a simple hell world text test. No other functionality on the homepage.

Comment: "Homepage", ok, so you need a web-browser for the homepage so it is indeed a web-application.

Answer (score 0):

You have a Web-Application. Web-Applications on Spring are using the Servlet-Specification.

The filetype of your application is a bundled `.war`-file, who is ready for deployment on a Servlet-Container.

In production state-of-the-art is a servlet-container like

- Tomcat
- JBoss / Wildfly
- Jetty

They are running performance-optimized on a hardened operation-systems like Linux or Solaris. Starting a JRE who can not debug by default.

They use a VM-flag called `--server` what brings big performace-improvements from about 5-10%. But the 20x times faster execution does not seems a compiler-flag problem.

Do you have a Antivirus-Program running? That might give such a impact.

Try to install tomcat, package the application for production and copy the `.war`-file to tomcat's `webapps`-folder. This might give the performace-improvement you are looking for.